# Writing the columns or Rows of a Matrix in Suffix Notation

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation

I have the following matrix:

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\vec{a}\\
\vec{b}\\
\vec{c}
\end{bmatrix}$$

and the following vectors:

$$\vec{a} = (a_1 , a_2 , a_3)\\
\vec{b} = (b_1 , b_2 , b_3)\\
\vec{a} = (c_1 , c_2 , c_3)$$

Is there a way to express this matrix in suffix notation using the vectors above?

Any hints?

Comment: Maybe something like $M_{ij} = \delta_{i,1}a_j+\delta_{i,2}b_j+\delta_{i,3}c_j$?

Comment: Perhaps with $M^T$ ?

Answer (score 2):

I would write this as
$$
M_{ij} = \delta_{i,1}a_j+\delta_{i,2}b_j+\delta_{i,3}c_j
$$